# org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read a JSON file in which I have a series of integer data but when read tells me it can not convert from JSONObject to JSONArray

Part of the JSON file structure is:

```
{  
    "data": [  
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],  
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],  
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],  
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],  
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],  
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
    ],  
    "time": 0.2  
},
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


try {

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Carriots\\dos.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


    // loop array
    JSONArray tag = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");


    Iterator iterator = tag.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());

}
```

Comment: With your code the program compiles and runs. I used JSON simple . Do you have the exact stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

`JSONArray tag = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below to get JSONArray from key `data`

```
JSONArray tag = (JSONArray) jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

`jsonObject.get()` will return you `Object` not any `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JSONTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        try {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Carriots\\dos.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            JSONArray data = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("data");

            for(Object o: data){
                System.out.println(o);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

output:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: The error persists , I changed the libraries org.json.simple ... to org.json and console shows me the same error ..

Comment: @Bufank85 You cannot use `org.json` for the way that you are doing it, to cast your object to an Array you _need_ to use the `org.json.simple` library. Which I don't see any problem with you doing.

Comment: I copied all your code and output continues to show the same                                                                                                              java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
 at JSONTest.main(JSONTest.java:20)

Comment: @Bufank85 note: that I removed the `,` on the last line of your JSON as that is not a valid JSON. Everything else seems to work for me completely fine with the code that I've provided; I'm using Java 8 but I don't think that should make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator to process the array data. Be sure to use Object rather than String or Integer since you will get errors converting JSONObject to one of these values.

```
package jsonProcessing;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonNumReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/JSON/numbers.json"));

        JSONArray array = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("data");

        Iterator<Object>iterator = array.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```