# json rest API's error : ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am a beginner in Programming
so I have this response from an API :

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Postcode not found"
}
```

And this is my code to return just the country and region for A particular postcode

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    break;
}

JSONObject jsObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsObject.get("result");

output.append("The Details for ").append(postcode).append(" are:\n");


if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        //String region = jsonObject.get("region").toString();
        output.append(jsonObject.get("region").toString()).append(", ");

        // String country = jsonObject.get("country").toString();
        output.append(jsonObject.get("country").toString()).append("\n");

    }
```

My code gives me the error:

> ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to
>   org.json.JSONArray

Comment: Your API response doesn't have country or region. It's giving you 404.

Comment: Check out the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161185/org-json-simple-jsonarray-cannot-be-cast-to-org-json-simple-jsonobject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161185/org-json-simple-jsonarray-cannot-be-cast-to-org-json-simple-jsonobject)

Comment: I mean if you enter the correct post code the API response gives {"status":200,"result":{"postcode":"L6 6DG","quality":1,"eastings":337113,"northings":391146,"country":"England","nhs_ha":"North  ...}}

Answer (score 0):

`jsObject.get("result");` is an Object not an array so following line will throw Class cast exception.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsObject.get("result");
```

JSON from your comment

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": {
        "postcode": "L6 6DG",
        "quality": 1,
        "eastings": 337113,
        "northings": 391146,
        "count‌​ry": "England",
        "nhs_h‌​a": "North ...
    }
}
```

This line should be

```
JSONObject result = jsObject.getJsonObject("result");
```